# Getting 400 response on GET request from AJAX

Tags: ajax, api

I'm trying to access my API using AJAX with the simple following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://SERVER_IP/API-test/public/login/username/userpass",
    crossDomain: 'true',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(whatever){
        alert('HTTP request is a success');
        console.log(whatever);
    },
    error: function(errorText){
        console.log("Error Test: ",errorText);
    }
});
```

and in response I get 400 (Bad request) from the server. This code generates following request:

```
http://SERVER_IP/API-test/public/login/username/userpass?callback=jQuery1112009842987591400743_1429090394748&_=1429090394749
```

I guess that the problem is in the part this part:

```
?callback=jQuery1112009842987591400743_1429090394748&_=1429090394749
```

that is added to my request.

How could I avoid this? Or could be the root of the problem somewhere else?

Comment: Why don't you use POST instead of GET?

Answer (score 0):

Whether the Query Parameters result in a HTTP Code 400 depends on you server implementation.
Bot parameters are added by [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to avoid issues with caching.

The `_` parameter includes the current timestamp to avoid caching.

The `callback` parameter is added because you are querying a "remote" server (= crossdomain) with [jsonp "technique"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#How_it_works), which means the url is not same as the url the javascript/html/etc files have been loaded from.

Beside that you are querying a login endpoint (at least it is named like that) and do not send any verification data like username or password. When performing a GET request, these information needs to be included in the query part. Maybe the server returns "Bad Request", because the credentials are missing?

Comment: I've made the request using postman with same URL and everything works fine, so I'm not sure where is the error.

Comment: And it's correct, add-on to my URL is not the problem. I've send the URL, from the question, using Postman and response was good.

Comment: Did you set all the same request parameters? Investigate which properties differ between the request you performed via postman and the one performed by jQuery. Use Developer Tools Network Tab in your browser for the latter one (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#network-resource-details).
There must be a difference, otherwise the issue is server-side (e.g. randomly accepting and denying requests).